# Propriedade value de input não funciona com Angular

Tags: html5, angular, input

Estou tendo alguns problemas com a propriedade `value` de um campo de texto:

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="row">

    <div class="col s4 input-field">

      <input
        id="campo"
        type="text"
        value="exemplo de texto"/>
      <label for="campo">campo</label>

    </div>

    <!-- demais campos -->

  </form>
</div>
```

Ao utilizar a propriedade no componente, o Angular simplesmente a ignora, e o campo sai vazio, mesmo que seja utilizado números ou texto. Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: Se entendi bem, sem fazer **property binding - []** não via funcionar mesmo.

Comment: e não é que era isso mesmo?

Answer (score 0):

Importa o modulo `FormsModule` e usa `[(ngModel)]` no lugar de  `value`.